# Accidental use of built in function as variable name?

Tags: vba, excel

I have been writing some VBA code to produce charts automatically, and at one point named a variable "CHARTTITLE" not realizing that this is a member of the Chart object. I have deleted this variable upon realizing my mistake. However, since doing so, wherever I employ something like

```
Charts(1).ChartTitle.Text =
```

It will automatically auto-capitalize to

```
Charts(1).CHARTTITLE.Text
```

I have tried search and replace over the entire project from .CHARTTITLE to .ChartTitle to no avail. I have also tried employing Option Explicit also without effect. I am worried that there is now some sort of memory issue or that I've overwritten something important. Is there any way to reset this back to its default state?

Comment: Try running Rob Bovey's "Code Cleaner" add-in on your file (always useful to run this if you have any kind of often-edited VBA project...) http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately I am running a 64-bit system which isn't supported.

Answer (score 2):

It's a benign effect and it's a long-standing bug relating to the way that VBA stores itself internally. A couple of things to try:

1. Change the first occurrence of CHARTTITLE in the module, or if in multiple modules in the first module that appears in the project explorer.
2. Export the module, remove it from the project, edit it using your favourite text editor and reimport it.

Comment: I just tried both of these methods and they unfortunately did not work. As long as it is benign as you mentioned then I'm OK with it, though I think it causes some OCD to kick in. I would like to understand more about why this behaviour occurs however.